# Select the first Truthy column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, vectorization

I'm working on optimizing some code for speed and I understand that .apply within Pandas is not the optimal method for data processing. I'm looking to optimize this code in some way.

Say you have two columns like such

| Set_One | Set_Two |
| --- | --- |
| 'Foo' | '' |
| '' | 'Bar' |
| 'Foo' | 'Bar' |

If I were to want the first truthy value from the two columns in an apply statement, I could just use
`df.apply(lambda x : x.Set_One or x.Set_Two)`

This would result in

| Result |
| --- |
| 'Foo' |
| 'Bar' |
| 'Foo' |

But this slows down as the data set gets larger. Not by much considering that it's a fairly simple comparison.

The nice solution would be if I could do `result = df['Set_One'] or df['Set_Two']` but the truth value of a series is ambiguous. Using a `&` or `|` operator doesn't consider truthiness (or work on strings for that matter).

What is the best practice for this comparison?

So far, I've tried just a vectorized function that is functionally just returning the first truthy value.

```
def return_truthy(val1, val2):
    return val1 or val2

vec_truthy = np.vectorize(return_truthy)

vec_truthy(df['Set_One'], df['Set_Two'])
```

Using this function does result in about a 10x speed improvement, but it doesn't exactly look *elegant*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [`numpy.logical_or`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) function.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Set_One":["Foo", "", "Foo"], 
                   "Set_Two":["", "Bar", "Bar"]})
print(np.logical_or(df["Set_One"], df["Set_Two"]))
```

Output:

```py
0    Foo
1    Bar
2    Foo
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice one @jared ;)

Comment: @mozway I may not have the reputation you have, but I'm getting there. (I'm still not sure how you got over 100k last year.)

Comment: Thanks! Of course I didn’t even think to look at Numpys other methods. Appreciate the fast answer.

Answer (score 1):

What jared said above is the best way I think, I just wanted to add this also addresses the speed issue mentioned in the question. Using the below speed test

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit

# Create a large dataframe
data = {
    "Set_One": ["foo", None, "foo"] * 100000,
    "Set_Two": [None, "bar", "bar"] * 100000,
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Method 1: Using df.apply
def method1():
    result = df.apply(lambda x: x.Set_One or x.Set_Two, axis=1)


# Method 2: Using np.logical_or
def method2():
    result = np.logical_or(df["Set_One"], df["Set_Two"])


# Measure execution time for method 1
time_method1 = timeit.timeit(method1, number=10)

# Measure execution time for method 2
time_method2 = timeit.timeit(method2, number=10)

print("Time taken using df.apply(lambda x: x.Set_One or x.Set_Two):", time_method1)
print(
    'Time taken using np.logical_or(df["Set_One"], df["Set_Two"]):', time_method2)

times_faster = time_method1 / time_method2
print("Method 2 is", times_faster, "times faster than method 1")
```

I get the following result

```
Time taken using df.apply(lambda x: x.Set_One or x.Set_Two): 20.352213299999903
Time taken using np.logical_or(df["Set_One"], df["Set_Two"]): 0.05363929999998618
Method 2 is 379.4272725409382 times faster than method 1
```